# Youtube api playlist id

Tags: php, api, youtube

I am using the test code found @ http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html to create a playlist:

```
$newPlaylist = $yt->newPlaylistListEntry();
$newPlaylist->summary = $yt->newDescription()->setText($desc);
$newPlaylist->title = $yt->newTitle()->setText($title);
// post the new playlist
$postLocation = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists';
try {
  $playlist = $yt->insertEntry($newPlaylist, $postLocation);
  } 
catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The playlist is created, but how can I get the id or url of the playlist that was just created?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I have managed to get a bit further but I still can't get the playlistID. Here is what I did:

instead of:

```
$playlist = $yt->insertEntry($newPlaylist, $postLocation);
```

I used :

```
$playlist = $yt->insertEntry($newPlaylist, $postLocation, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_PlaylistListEntry');
```

But when I try to get the id by `$playlist->getPlaylistID()` or `$playlist->playlistId->text` I get the same exception which says :

> The yt:playlistId element is not supported in versions earlier than 2.

even if I have set it earlier with `$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete and utter hack, I had the same exact problem, so I went into the class at Zend/Gdata/YouTube/PlaylistListEntry.php on line 229 I commented out the if else statement.

```
 /**
 * Returns the Id relating to the playlist.
 *
 * @throws Zend_Gdata_App_VersionException
 * @return Zend_Gdata_YouTube_Extension_PlaylistId  The id of this playlist.
 */
public function getPlaylistId()
{
    /*if (($this->getMajorProtocolVersion() == null) ||
        ($this->getMajorProtocolVersion() == 1)) {
        require_once 'Zend/Gdata/App/VersionException.php';
        throw new Zend_Gdata_App_VersionException('The yt:playlistId ' .
            'element is not supported in versions earlier than 2.');
    } else {*/
        return $this->_playlistId;
    //}
}
```

I would LOVE for someone to show us how to fix this the right way, but this made it so

```
function printPlaylistListEntry($playlistListEntry, $showPlaylistContents = false)
    {

      $this->yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
      echo '<br>Title: ' . $playlistListEntry->title->text . "\n";
      echo '<br>Description: ' . $playlistListEntry->description->text . "\n";
      echo '<br>playlistId: ' . $playlistListEntry->playlistId->text . "\n";
```

... (from the youtube v2 php api).

will return the playlistid.

Title: *therighttitle*

Description: *therightdescription*

playlistId: *therightplaylistId*

edit: I think this may be a better solution:

```
if ($this->getMajorProtocolVersion() < 2) {
        require_once 'Zend/Gdata/App/VersionException.php';
        throw new Zend_Gdata_App_VersionException('The yt:playlistId ' .
            'element is not supported in versions earlier than 2.');
    } else {

        return $this->_playlistId;
    }
```

replace the getPlaylistId() function with this, follows the logic of the preceding getDescription function, and its less hacky. Again completely open to critiques on why this is or is not a good idea from the zend people.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special hacks to make this work.  You just need to explicitly set the protocol version for the $playlist variable, along with the $yt variable.  As you stated, set the major protocol version for $yt earlier:

```
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
```

Then after you initialize $playlist, set the protocol on that as well:

```
$playlist = $yt->insertEntry($newPlaylist, $postLocation, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_PlaylistListEntry');
$playlist->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
```

Once you do this, you should be able to get your playlist ID no problem :)

```
$playlist_id = $playlist->getPlaylistID();
```